# how to switch audio input between inbuilt mic and headset mic after a bluetooth headset is connected in android?

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, headset

I am working with a voice recognition app. After a bluetooth headset is successfully connected to my android device, I want to freely switch audio input between the inbuilt mic and headset mic, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to switch bluetooth headset mic.

```
AudioManager audiomanager= (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context
            .AUDIO_SERVICE);
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED);
    mContext.registerReceiver(mBluetoothScoReceiver, intentFilter);
audiomanager.startBluetoothSco();
```

and listen for the broadcast receiver.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBluetoothScoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1);

        if (state == AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED) {
            // Start recording audio
            log("audio connected");
            startRecording();
        } else if(state == AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED){
            log("audio disconnected");
        }
    }
};
```

and for switching(to disconnect bluetooth headset mic) you can use this code.

```
mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
```

Comment: After AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED is recieved, startRecording() is still using inbuilt mic

Comment: I invoke startRecording() outside mBluetoothScoReceiver, does that matter?

Comment: You should start recording only after receiving the audio state connected broadcast

Comment: my code is very similar with yours, and it works perfectly in android 4.4.4, while not in 5.x or 6.x or 7.x

Comment: add this line before caling startBluetoothSco(). mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL); u may need to add permission.

Comment: Also u need to handle voice recording intent in your app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964406/i-need-to-add-my-voice-search-app-to-complete-action-using-in-android-with-blu/43075899#43075899