# I need to add my Voice Search app to “Complete action using” in Android with Bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth

I would like to see my app in the "complete action using" list when i press the call button on my bluetooth headset.
Currently, i am only seeing "Google" and "SVoice app" as two options.

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
         <action         android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION"/>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
       <action   
android:name="android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

I don't see my app in the "complete action using" list.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the below intent for that.

[Voice search intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#ACTION_VOICE_SEARCH_HANDS_FREE)